# Display Search Results after search 1st link

Tags: search

As we know that when we search wordpress based site it shows this type URL on browser

__http://www.wordpressdemo.com/?s=wordpress

now at this moment our query is **wordpress**

for demo please view below link

http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/search.php

its first result is

http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=88&name=WordPress

my requirement is when user search a query wordpress automatic show 1st result post Instead of result page.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking here and what these links are? Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: when user search a query wordpress automatic show 1st result post Instead of result page.well @s_ha_dum answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting to the first result of a search is a very unfriendly thing to do to your visitors and can quite possibly prevent them from ever finding the content they need, but it is very easy to do:

```
function redir_first_wpse_49208() {
  if (is_search()) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (!empty($wp_query->posts)) {
      wp_redirect( get_permalink( $wp_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
      exit;
    }
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redir_first_wpse_49208');
```

Comment: thank you very much and suggestion but i am using this where query have only one result.

Comment: I don't see how you can guarantee with any certainty that an `?s=` search will only return a single result.

Comment: hmm....probability btw is it possible i can pass query as title to end result page

Comment: @birgire why you remove 'exit;' from above code ?

Comment: I'm adding the `exit` part not removing it. We need it after the `wp_redirect()` call. @BilalRaj